# Wordpress Image issues

Tags: wordpress, image

Hi I seem to have an odd situation going on with my images. I am able to upload them in the media library as well as FTP. I can see them in there but when I tried to upload an additional image to replace one on my homepage, it does not show in the browser. It also seemed as if a couple images were pulling from different folders than the url I used in the post. However, those images didn't have a problem showing up in the browser. The one I'm missing is in the right place as far as I can see.
I copied the url and that works fine in the browser but not on my homepage. I haven't changed anything with my database or permissions.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say from this perspective. Have you used the enable media replace plugin?

Comment: I'm not sure what @KaiQing means by a media replace plugin, I wouldn't think that would be necessary. Can you share a link so we can get a better idea of what's happening? It could be from a number of different issues; incorrect URLs, permissions, etc.

Comment: @rpl - I only suggest enable-media-replace so they can try replacing the media file directly instead of uploading a new one and assigning it. By the description of the issue, I am not sure how they are trying to replace, or how they're trying to use the images. It's a little unclear.

Comment: @KaiQing I agree that it is unclear, and I can see why you'd think that. We need some further explanation of what is to be replaced. I think this may be in reference to the featured image, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: I have not enabled media replace plugin. The url is http://www.sacrealtor.org/events_center/

I'm not using featured image for the images in question. Thanks

Comment: I'm using the Chromatic theme and it has options for pages to be widgetized template or default. I just discovered that when I change the page back to default, the image shows up......... but I need it to be the widgetized layout.